# How to put app in background and back to foreground using Selenium on iOS devices?

Tags: ios, background, appium, device, foreground

How to put app in background and relaunch in Appium `iOS` for `iOS` 9.3 and ios 10.0?
I've tried runInBackground(10) but it works only for `Android` not working for `iOS`.

Comment: We are automation an ios App on different versions(ios 9.3 and ios 10.0) using selenium, here we have to verify the session after closing the App and opening the App.

Comment: Modified question, code formatting

Answer (score 0):

To put app to background for 10 second please follow below syntax :
`driver.runAppInBackground(Duration.ofSeconds(10));`

For more details please follow:

https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/InteractsWithApps.html#runAppInBackground-java.time.Duration-

https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/commands/device/app/background-app/